# Can I use smooch.io android SDK for making a chat application between users,group chat etc?

Tags: android, smooch

Was searching for a chat service SDK and server with API, looked into smooch.io which seemed to be the same.However, now I came to an understanding that it is for one admin appuser and many users communicating to that admin and I cannot create group chats or user to user chat with smooch.io .Since the documentation is not clear enough about describing this,please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

check out [quickblox](http://quickblox.com/) SDK,

There are examples in the documentation,
use it for private, groupchat, voice, video, file transfer

Comment: but only 20/s push notifications and chat messages is a concern.

Comment: That basically means.  Its free for you to test and use when in development environment,  once you want to go live,  you need to buy a particular package as per your needs. Bcoz the restrictions for starter pack doesnt match the needs of production environment.